# I am looking for a method to select a value from Sheet C, match it to a value in Sheet A, and populate C from A

Tags: excel

I am trying to auto-populate Sheet C from data using two other sheets in the same workbook. I am using vlookup to get data from Sheet B onto Sheet C (columns D - H). Columns B - C will also use vlookup.

I am having trouble figuring out a way to pull multiple data from Sheet A onto Sheet C based on a single value from C.

When I select a value from 'Sheet C'!A2 dropdown, I'd like to locate the matching value in Column A of Sheet A. When it matches, I'm wondering if it is feasible to pull all the data to the right of the matched value in Sheet A into the corresponding blank spaces of Sheet C.

Sheet C
[image: Sheet C]

Sheet A
[image: Sheet A]

Expected result if I selected AlbCreERT2 in A2 of Sheet C:
[image: Expected Result]

What I am trying to avoid is a workbook with 20 dedicated sheets, one for each particular value (with its data already populated). Any help would be appreciated. I'd also value suggestions for an alternative, even if the alternative is the workbook with 20 dedicated sheets.

Comment: You have to fill-up `AlbCreERT2` from `A2:A12` to `Sheet A`. Then you can easily pull all the information easily by matching from dropdown menu.

Comment: You can use `FILTER` if you have access to the new formulas but as stated above, you will need to have the values in `Column A` fill down. You will need to use VBA if that is not an option